# Конкатенация данных и запись в массив из dataGridView

Tags: c#

Как правильно произвести подобное действие ?

Получаю `System.NullReferenceException`

Я так понимаю это из за пустой ячейки

```
// Копировать текст
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string[] mas = new string[dataGridView.RowCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
    {

        mas[i] = dataGridView["column1", i].Value.ToString() + "|" + 
                 dataGridView["column2", i].Value.ToString() + "|" + 
                 dataGridView["column3", i].Value.ToString() + "|" + 
                 dataGridView["column4", i].Value.ToString() + "|" + 
                 dataGridView["column5", i].Value.ToString()
                 ;
    }

    StringBuilder clipData = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object value in mas)
        clipData.AppendLine(value.ToString());
    Clipboard.SetText(clipData.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, можно применить [Null-conditional operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.`:

```
dataGridView["column1", i].Value?.ToString()
```

Во-вторых, в данном конкретном случае можно просто убрать `ToString`. Этот метод так и так вызывается автоматически, если операнд участвует в строковом выражении. Проверка на `null` при этом не нужна.

```
dataGridView["column1", i].Value + "|"
```

В-третьих, можно сократить код следующим образом:

```
var cells = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells;

mas[i] = cells["column1"].Value + "|" +
         cells["column2"].Value + "|" +
```

и т. д.

В-четвёртых, раз уж применяется `StringBuilder`, то нужно использовать его на всю катушку. При этом выкидываем ненужный массив.

```
var clipData = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
{
    var cells = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells;

    clipData
        .Append(cells["column1"].Value).Append('|')
        .Append(cells["column2"].Value).Append('|')
        .Append(cells["column3"].Value).Append('|')
        .Append(cells["column4"].Value).Append('|')
        .Append(cells["column5"].Value).AppendLine();
}

Clipboard.SetText(clipData.ToString());
```

Таким образом избавляемся от множества лишних аллокаций памяти.

Comment: Как сделать всё тоже самое но в .txt файл ? Пытаюсь использовать File.AppendAllText, но он сохраняет не в том же порядке как это в clipData